# Theorem 2.18 in Rudin's RCA. I don't understand the proof.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Theorem 2.18 in RCA says:

> **Theorem 2.18** Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space in which every open set is $\sigma$-compact. Let $\lambda$ be any positive Borel measure on $X$ such that $\lambda(K)<\infty$ for every compact set $K$. Then $\lambda$ is regular.

The author proves the theorem by taking a measure $\mu$ determined by the positive linear functional $\Lambda$ given by $\Lambda f = \int_X f d\lambda$ for each $f\in C_c(X)$. And he *shows* that $\mu$ equals $\lambda$.

Okay, I see that if $\mu=\lambda$, then $\lambda$ is regular because $\mu$ is. This is totally okay.

What I don't understand is, why should we *prove* that $\mu=\lambda$? The measure $\mu$ comes from the Theorem 2.14, isn't it? The author has already proven the uniqueness of a measure representing the given positive linear funtional on $C_c(X)$ in the Theorem 2.14.

So why? I should've missed something.

Comment: No, he's already proved the uniqueness of the _regular_ measure corresponding to $\lambda$; that leaves open the possibility of non-uniqueness for non-regular measures (and in fact somewhere in the first few chapters there's an example of this non-uniqueness).